# Calculate duration of True values in column with an index containing seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the duration of which a column is True with a index containing seconds within a dataframe.

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0.0: False, 0.5: False, 1.0:False, 1.5:True, 2.0:True, 4.0:False, 8.0:True,10.0:False}})

>>> df
          a
0.0   False
0.5   False
1.0   False
1.5    True
2.0    True
4.0   False
8.0    True
10.0  False
```

The index of the dataframe contains seconds. I think the most appropriate method would be to extract the first occurance of each sections of True values, until a false is found and have a running total. RT is the running total
The result would be something like this:

```
    >>> df
          a
0.0   False
0.5   False
1.0   False
1.5    True < - found first occurance  (1.5)
2.0    True
4.0   False < - found false (4.0) (running total: 4-1.5 + RT = 2.5)
8.0    True < - found first occurance (8.0)
10.0  False < - found false (10.0) (running total: 10-8 + RT = 4.5)

RT = 4.5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper columns that uniquely label the `False` values -- these numbers indicate the *possible* ends of a `True` streak. Then merge the False rows with the first True row that belongs to the previous streak and calculate the sum of the time difference.

```
df = df.rename_axis(index='time').reset_index()
df['end'] = (~df['a']).cumsum()
#   time      a  end
#0   0.0  False    1
#1   0.5  False    2
#2   1.0  False    3
#3   1.5   True    3
#4   2.0   True    3
#5   4.0  False    4
#6   8.0   True    4
#7  10.0  False    5

res = pd.merge(df[df['a'].eq(False)],
               df[df['a'].eq(True)].assign(end=df['end']+1).drop_duplicates('end'),
               on='end')
#   time_x    a_x  end  time_y   a_y
#0     4.0  False    4     1.5  True
#1    10.0  False    5     8.0  True

(res['time_x'] - res['time_y']).sum()
#4.5
```

---

To explain the merge, the left DataFrame is just every row in the original that contains False:

```
df[df['a'].eq(False)]
#   time      a  end
#0   0.0  False    1
#1   0.5  False    2
#2   1.0  False    3
#5   4.0  False    4
#7  10.0  False    5
```

The right DataFrame is a little more complicated. I take only the True rows, but drop_duplicates on `end` because we only want to keep the **first** True when there are consecutive True values. Finally because we want to match the True with the False that comes after it, we need to add one to `end`.

```
df[df['a'].eq(True)].assign(end=df['end']+1).drop_duplicates('end')
#   time     a  end
#3   1.5  True    4
#6   8.0  True    5
```

Now by merging `on='end'` we are able to match the first True (in a possible consecutive group of True values) with the first False value that follows it. Since we brought the index along as `'time'` we can calculate the time difference between these observations.

Comment: Is it possible to break down the pd.merge? Or just describe what you are doing?

Comment: @RMRiver I added some details to illustrate what the frames are that go into the merge, but the merge itself is a simple match between the two Frames on the column 'end'